# Which one is better to use: Google APIs Client Library for PHP (OR) Online OAuth 2.0 for Login directly?

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-console

I am currently trying to implement [Google's OAuth 2.0 for Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login) in my PHP application : so far I have been able to achieve ** [this](http://techyyz.com/openid.html) **.

I have registered the application on Google API Console and got the necessary parameters to be used for the OAuth 2.0 APIs from Google  .

I was wondering which one would be the best option to implement? [Object oriented approach using Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/) OR [Google's OAuth 2.0 for Login](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login)?

What are the benefits of using Client Library over direct Online API or vice-versa? I am looking for a long term maintainable code. So please answer by keeping this in mind and if possible the pros and cons of both approaches.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is a very constructive question... Furthermore I think that using another service as your login system can be very bad.... http://bits.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/10/22/amazon-cloud-service-goes-down-and-takes-some-popular-web-sites-with-it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like what you're doing is working, so what's the problem?  Presumably the PHP library has lots of other stuff beyond the simple OAuth login; if you need that stuff, then you should probably use that library.

Comment: I wasn't able to add the standard library to Symfony framework while I posted the question. So I was trying to find out if I was doing the right choice or not. 

@TimBray: As you said, the PHP library has lots of other stuff beyond OAuth. We already started using Calendar API with service accounts. So I am going to stick on to the standard library. Thank you.